# Let $H ≤ G$ and $Hg$ be a right coset of $H$ in $G$. Prove that the set $\{k^{-1}|k \in Hg\}$ is a left coset of $H$ in $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I currently and studying for my exams and this is one of the warm up questions, however I am struggling to understand how to approach it, my current attempt has been:

$k=hg$

$\implies k^{-1}=g^{-1}h^{-1}$

$\implies k^{-1}hg=1$

$\implies k^{-1}hgg_1h_1=g_1h_1 \in gH$

But this feels wrong, I am not sure how to approach this as I have been struggling with it for quite awhile now, any help would be appreciated.

It also follows on by saying "*deduce that there is a bijection between the left and right cosets of H in G*" so any tips for that would be appreciated.

Edit: Thank you for the help, most of this has been resolved in a way that has allowed me to figure it out for myself.

Comment: $k^{-1} \in g^{-1}H$. The left coset in question is $g^{-1}H$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, I think I am just confused about what the question itself is asking, would it be possible to break it down a bit for me? Thank you!

Comment: You need to show that $k^{-1}$ is an element of $zH $ (then converse), that is, that each $k^{-1}$ is equal to $zh$ for some $h $ in $H $. Note that this only uses the definition of left coset. (The previous comment suggests said that $z $ I am searching for is $g^{-1} $.)@Radon

Comment: To achieve all this you need to do manipulation of the type you've alreay done, but keeoing in mind the equalities/results you want.

Comment: @Any Thanks for the response, I have edited it to get $k=hg \implies k^{-1}=g^{-1}h^{-1} \in g^{-1}H$, thus showing that elements of the set are elements of a left coset, however I am struggling to show that the elements of the left coset are elements the set.

Comment: I think I have it, could please confirm if this is right? As $g^{-1}H=\{g^{-1}h|h \in H\}$, pick $h^{-1} \in H$. Therefore $g^{-1}h^{-1} \in g^{-1}H$ But, $g^{-1}h^{-1}=(hg)^{-1}=k^{-1}$ where $k \in Hg$. So the set is a left coset of H in G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z\in Hg $. Then $z=hg$ so $z^{-1}= g^{-1}h^{-1}$, ie  $z^{-1}\in g^{-1}H$. Conversely, let $z\in g^{-1}H $. Then $z=g ^{-1}h$ for some $h\in H $. Then $zh^{-1}g=1$ so $z^ {-1}=h^{-1}g \in Hg $.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Any, im afraid I cannot rep with my current number of points but thanks to you I have been able to understand the concept much more clearly and figure it out (sorta) with just hints. :)

Answer (score 0):

All elements of $Hg$ are of the form $hg$ for some $h\in H$

so inverse of the elements of $Hg$ looks like $g^{-1}h^{-1}$ for some $h \in H$

So all the elements are in the set $g^{-1}H$ .

Now note that all elements of $g^{-1}H$ belongs to the set $\{k^{−1}|k\in Hg\}$

(As inverse of group elements exist inside the group)

So  $g^{-1}H$= $\{k^{−1}|k\in Hg\}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I do not quite understand why $g^{-1}H$ belongs to the set however.

Comment: Consider the action that takes every element of Hg to it's inverse. It is clearly bijective. What more can u say ?

Comment: @Sadhu I don't see how the set $g^{-1}H$ is an element of the set u are talking about.

Comment: @Soumik Oh right, is it a bijection because if, as you say, you take a homomorphism: $\phi(gh)=h^{-1}g^{-1}$, it is bijective, well defined, and thus we have an isomorphism between the left and right cosets?

Comment: No not homomorphism unless the group is abelian. It is simply a map which happens to be a bijection

Comment: Observe that in $g^{-1}h^{-1}$, $h^{-1}$ belongs to $H$ since H is a subgroup.

Comment: I was under the impression that a homomorphism required not that the group is abelian, I am pretty sure of that anyway. I am not sure why $g^{−1}h^{−1}, h^{-1}$ belonging to $H$ tells us that we have an isomorphism?